# Duplicate & Reduce Multi-column Data in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

Say I have the following data in an Excel spreadsheet:

```
Andy      Dick          
Brad      Penny       Paisley       
Charlie   Daniels     Brown       Sheen     Schwab
Dave      Robinson          
Evan      Longoria          
Frank     Sinatra     Thomas
```

What I need to do is reduce to two columns based on the parent-child relationship in the data to look like this:

```
Andy    Dick
Brad    Penny
Brad    Paisley
Charlie Daniels
Charlie Brown
Charlie Sheen
Charlie Schwab
Dave    Robinson
Evan    Longoria
Frank   Sinatra
Frank   Thomas
```

I'm not really much of an Excel guy, but there's gotta be a macro I can write or something right? Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub ParentChild()

    Dim vaNames As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim aReturn() As String
    Dim lCnt As Long

    'Fill an array with values
    vaNames = Sheet1.Range("A1:E6").Value

    'loop through the "rows"
    For i = LBound(vaNames, 1) To UBound(vaNames, 1)
        'loop through the "cols" starting with 2
        For j = LBound(vaNames, 2) + 1 To UBound(vaNames, 2)
            'if there's a last name present
            If Len(vaNames(i, j)) > 0 Then
                'fill a new array with the first and last names
                lCnt = lCnt + 1
                ReDim Preserve aReturn(1 To 1, 1 To lCnt)
                aReturn(1, lCnt) = vaNames(i, LBound(vaNames, 2)) & " " & vaNames(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    'write the new array out to a range
    Sheet1.Range("A10").Resize(UBound(aReturn, 2), 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aReturn)

End Sub
```